# How can i update cuDNN on azure ML studio from 8.2 to 8.6 while running on pytorch and tensorflow kernel

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service, cudnn

I have uninstalled and installed cuDNN but still it is giving error. I have tried to downgrade tensorflow and pytorch but azure runs on the default version.[This is the error am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmkAi.png)

I have installed cuDNN version it installs the version 8.6 but still runs on 8.2 only. Can anyone help me how to call the latest version of cuDNN in this case 8.6 anfter !pip installing it ?

Comment: what is the version it shows when you do `pip show <package_name>`

Comment: It shows cuDNN 8.2

Comment: There it should show 8.6 if you have installed cuDNN version 8.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command.

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163
```

This command uninstalls the current version of the package and installs specified one.

Currently installed one.

[image]

After running above command.

[image]

[image]